# projectile motion find the angle

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics, projectile-motion

I would please like help on the following question related to projectile motion.

> An object is projected in a **$60$ m/s** velocity with a $\theta$ angle to the ground. If the object has $30^\circ$ angle to the ground at a height of **$120$ m** from the projected point, find $\theta$.

[image: image for the question is here]

I seperated the velocity at above position into to parts and found the velocities for each factors seperately.

```
↑ v = u+at
    = u sin θ - 10t

→v = u+at
   =u cos θ

tan 30 = u sin θ - 10t / u cos θ
```

What to do after this result ?

Comment: Would the object even reach the height of 120m??

Comment: @idpd15 yes of course

Comment: **Hint:** Don't put `homework help` in your title and also don't give a problem with zero work. Voting to close.

Comment: Well your question says $6$ but your picture says $60$ so you should probably double check everything to make sure you have all the right values first

Comment: @Brenton Yes, my fault. Not 6 it is 60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  y &= 60t\sin \theta-5t^2 \\
  120 &= 60t\sin \theta-5t^2 \\
  24 &= t(12\sin \theta-t) \quad \cdots \cdots (1) \\
  \frac{v_{y}}{v_{x}} &= \frac{60\sin \theta-10t}{60\cos \theta} \\
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} &= \frac{6\sin \theta-t}{6\cos \theta} \\
  t &= 6\sin \theta-2\sqrt{3} \cos \theta \quad \cdots \cdots (2) \\
\end{align*}

Let $s = \sin \theta \, $ and substitute $(2)$ into $(1)$,
\begin{align*}
  24 &= \left[ 6s-2\sqrt{3(1-s^2)} \, \right]
        \left[ 6s+2\sqrt{3(1-s^2)} \, \right] \\
  24 &= 36s^2-12(1-s^2) \\
  4s^2 &= 3 \\
  \sin \theta &= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
  \theta &= 60^{\circ}
\end{align*}